# How to wrap an onclick event with quotes

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a function call in an onclick event to the data being returned. I haven't been able to figure out if I'm missing quotes anywhere. Could you provide any insight the correct to do this?

```
the_data = "<a onclick=popup_manager.getFormPopUp(" + options + ")>"+the_data+ "</a>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the value you use in the arguments of your function in quotes which are escaped from the body of the string which contains them:

```js
const options = 'foo';
let the_data = 'bar';
the_data = '<a onclick="popup_manager.getFormPopUp(\'' + options + '\'")>' + the_data + '</a>';
console.log(the_data);
```

Improving this approach, you could use a template literal to make the syntax less messy and avoid the need to escape the inner quotes:

```js
const options = 'foo';
let the_data = 'bar';
the_data = `<a onclick="popup_manager.getFormPopUp('${options}')>${the_data}</a>`;
console.log(the_data);
```

To take this another step further, you could follow best practice and remove the outdated inline `onclick` attribute, which should be avoided, and instead attach your event handlers unobtrusively, providing the arguments to the handler function through `data` attributes in your HTML:

```js
const options = 'foo';
let the_data = 'bar';
the_data = `<a href="#" data-options="${options}">${the_data}</a>`;

const container = document.querySelector('#container');
container.innerHTML = the_data;

container.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log(e.target.dataset.options)
});
```

```html
<div id="container">sdfsdf</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you want something like this?

```js
var div=document.getElementById("myDiv");
var element="<a onclick=foo()> Click Me</a>";

div.innerHTML+=element;

function foo(){
  console.log("Clicked..:)");
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use document.createElement to get the result you wanted

```js
let a = document.createElement("a");
a.innerHTML = the_data;
a.onclick = popup_manager.getFormPopUp(options);
```

then append 'a' to your html document